# SQL Server CE count number of rows in each table in a database

Tags: sql-server-ce

What query should I use if I want to get the number of rows in each table in a database. I am using SQL Server CE for my database.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable
```

Or if your table has a primary key (faster):

```
    public Int64 GetRowCount(string tableName)
    {
        object value = ExecuteScalar("SELECT CARDINALITY FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INDEXES WHERE PRIMARY_KEY = 1 AND TABLE_NAME = N'" + tableName + "'");
        if (value != null)
        {
            return (Int64)value;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can count the number of rows for each table from sys.objects linking to the ddps

see the query here..

http://codejupiter.com/questions/count-number-of-rows-in-each-table-in-a-database

Comment: Doesn't work here: `Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

Additional information: The specified table does not exist. [ @@sys.indexes ]`